# How to get all the possible matches of two lists?

Tags: java, algorithm

For example, I have a list which contains some Lecture instances, each lecture has a certain number of students attending this lecture and another list which contains some Classroom instances, each classroom has a maximum capacity.

Now I intend to assign each lecture in lecture list with a classroom in classroom list, all lectures in lecture class should have a classroom, then create a map to store this possibility.
And I want to return all these possible matches in the form of a set.
For example:

```
Classroom List: [Classroom1(50),Classroom2(70),Classroom3(80)]
Lecture list:   [Lecture1(50), Lecture2(70), Lecture3(50)]
```

Then we have 3 possible maps, which are:

```
{lecture1:classroom1, lecture2:classroom2, lecture3:classroom3} and
{lecture1:classroom1, lecture2:classroom3, lecture3:classroom2} and
{lecture1:classroom2, lecture2:classroom3, lecture3:classroom1}
```

After that, all possible maps should be stored in a set.

I am new to programming and has not learned algorithm yet, maybe that's why I'm so struggled on this, I'd be grateful if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: maybe you want to try some kind of framework, e.g. OptaPlanner

Comment: @KevinWallis Is there some other ways? I intend to write a class myself to solve this problem

Comment: the problem is, that depending on the number of class rooms, lectures, etc. the possibilities are exploding and so using an algorithm would be very good. Also it could be, that you cannot compute all possible solutions in a given amount of time because you have too much possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i got sucked in to this one and wrote a working solution

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class ClassMatcher {

        //The set of all possible matchings.
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>> set = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>>(); 
        // The current matching being built
    static ArrayList<Pair> cur = new ArrayList<Pair>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lecture[] l = { new Lecture(50, 1), new Lecture(70, 2), new Lecture(50, 3)};
        ArrayList<Classroom> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Classroom(50, 1), new Classroom(70, 2),
            new Classroom(100, 3)));

        for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                    //Fill with dummy values
            cur.add(new Pair(new Classroom(-1, -1), new Lecture(-1, -1)));
        }

        // Sort the arrays to save work in rec()
        Arrays.sort(l);
                //Sort classrooms in descending order
        Collections.sort(c, new Comparator<Classroom>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Classroom o1, Classroom o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2) * -1;
            }
        });

        recursive(l, c, 0);

        // Print all the sets
        for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("{");
            for (int j = 0; j < set.get(i).size(); j++) {
                System.out.print("Lecture " + set.get(i).get(j).l + ": "
                    + "Classroom " + set.get(i).get(j).c);
                if (j < set.get(i).size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("}");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void recursive(Lecture[] lectureList,
            ArrayList<Classroom> classroomList, int curLecture) {

        for (int i = 0; i < classroomList.size(); i++) {
            // if the classroom is smaller than the lecture we cna stop as the
            // lists are sorted so all other lectures will be to big for the
            // current classroom
            if (lectureList[curLecture].size > classroomList.get(i).size) {
                return;
            }

            //Match the current classroom to the current lecture and add to the working matching
            cur.set(curLecture, new Pair(classroomList.get(i), lectureList[curLecture]));

                //If there are more lectures to do then remove the used classroom and recursively call.
            if (curLecture < lectureList.length - 1) {
                Classroom tmp = classroomList.remove(i);
                recursive(lectureList, classroomList, curLecture + 1);
                classroomList.add(i, tmp);
            } 
                // If no Lectures left then add this matching to the set of all matchings. 
            else {
                ArrayList<Pair> copy = (ArrayList<Pair>) cur.clone();
                set.add(copy);
            }
        }

    }

}

class Classroom implements Comparable<Classroom> {

    int size;
    int number;

    public Classroom(int s, int n) {
        size = s;
        number = n;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Classroom o) {

        return Integer.compare(this.size, o.size);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return number + " (" + size + ")";
    }
}

class Lecture implements Comparable<Lecture> {

    int size;
    int number;

    public Lecture(int s, int n) {
        size = s;
        number = n;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Lecture o) {

        return Integer.compare(this.size, o.size);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return number + " (" + size + ")";
    }
}

class Pair {

    Classroom c;
    Lecture l;

    public Pair(Classroom c, Lecture l) {
        this.c = c;
        this.l = l;
    }
}
```

This gives the output

```
{Lecture 1 (50): Classroom 3 (100), Lecture 3 (50): Classroom 1 (50), Lecture 2 (70): Classroom 2 (70)}
{Lecture 1 (50): Classroom 2 (70), Lecture 3 (50): Classroom 1 (50), Lecture 2 (70): Classroom 3 (100)}
{Lecture 1 (50): Classroom 1 (50), Lecture 3 (50): Classroom 3 (100), Lecture 2 (70): Classroom 2 (70)}
{Lecture 1 (50): Classroom 1 (50), Lecture 3 (50): Classroom 2 (70), Lecture 2 (70): Classroom 3 (100)}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I think I understand what you posted, you're the best answer I suppose. But one more question is if I want to make the recursion method to be private, where should I initialize "cur"?

Comment: You could initialize cur inside of the recursive method. At the start of the method just check if cur.size() != lectureList.length, then go ahead and initialize it.

Comment: I use a map instead of pair list, can I just put this map as a parameter of this recursion method so I can just simply update k v in this map within this method, and then add it into a set? I think it could do but I'm a bit messy on this. I just learned recursion and it's really tricky to me.

Comment: private static Set<Map<Lecture, Classroom>> possibleAllocations(List<Lecture> lectures,
                                                              List<Classroom> classrooms,
                                                              int lectureCount,
                                                              Map<Lecture, Classroom> oneMap)

Comment: Yeah I think it should be able to work like that. I'd have to see code to know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

What you seem to be after is something known as the cartesian product.

[image]

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

You can do this with Java 8 streams

**All permutations**

```
// Just substitute the types and values for Lecture and Classroom instances
// I'm not going to do this for you
final List<String> first = Arrays.asList("foo","bar","baz");
final List<String> second = Arrays.asList("spam","ham","eggs");

final Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> objects = 
    first
      .stream()
      .flatMap(f -> 
         second
           .stream()
           .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(f, s)))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Your 'objects' **set** is going to contain Abstract entry maps which hold your combinations.

```
Set[
  Map{foo : spam}
  Map{foo : ham}
  Map{foo : eggs}
  Map{bar : spam}
  Map{bar : ham}
  Map{bar : eggs}
  Map{baz : spam}
  Map{baz : ham}
  Map{baz : eggs}
]
```

**Groups of combinations**

If you actually want 3 items in your set, you can do an intermediate collect on the second stream to collect into a data structure of your choice. Below shows that for a list, as I've already shown use of `Collectors.toSet()`

```
final Set<List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>>> objects = 
    first
      .stream()
      .map(f -> 
         second
           .stream()
           .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(f, s))
           .collect(Collectors.toList()))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Your 'objects' **set** is going to contain a list of Abstract entry maps which hold your combinations.

```
Set[
  List(
    Map{foo : spam}, Map{foo : ham}, Map{foo : eggs}
  ),
  List(
    Map{bar : spam}, Map{bar : ham}, Map{bar : eggs}
  ),
  List(
    Map{baz : spam}, Map{baz : ham}, Map{baz : eggs}
  )
]
```

This illustrates a simple cartesian product algorithm using Java 8 in a single functional statement. Should you wish to add any clauses or exclusions, you can use `filter` or any of the other higher order functions to manipulate the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will give you all the matches, you can use them like whatever you want

```
HasMap<Integer, Integer> match = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if(classroom[i] >= lecture[j]) {
            match.add(lecture[j], classroom[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

if you want seperate maps like for every classroom or lecture you can try this(example for classrooms)

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> classroom1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> classroom2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> classroom3 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            if(classroom[i] >= lecture[j]) {
                classroom1.add(lecture[j], classroom[i]);
            }
        }

        if(i == 1) {
            if(classroom[i] >= lecture[j]) {
                classroom2.add(lecture[j], classroom[i]);
            }
        }

        if(i == 2) {
            if(classroom[i] >= lecture[j]) {
                classroom3.add(lecture[j], classroom[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this you can create map of maps. Don't mind about correcting me or adding something. Have a good day!

Comment: Hi, I know this should work for one single map, but I want to return all the possible maps which satisfy my condition, which I find hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm in itself might look something like this using an nested for each loop:

```
 public Set<Object[]> allocateRooms(List<Lecture> lectures, List<ClassRoom> classRooms){

    Set<Object[]> returnSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for(Lecture l: lectures){
      for (ClassRoom c: classRooms){
        Object[] n = new Object[2];
        n[0] = c;
        n[1] = l;
        returnSet.add(n);
      }
    }
     return returnSet;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, you might misunderstand my condition. I intend to find all possible matches(as maps) assigned between classrooms and lectures and store these maps into a set. I really cannot find an effective way to do this.

Comment: The algorithm is similar, use a nested loop to go through two data structures that separately contain the objects. Store these in maps instead of Object arrays as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using Maps instead of arrays:

```
  public Set<Map<Lecture, ClassRoom>> allocateRooms(List<Lecture> lectures, List<ClassRoom> classRooms){

        Set<Map<Lecture, ClassRoom>> returnSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        for(Lecture l: lectures){
          for (ClassRoom c: classRooms){
            Map<Lecture, ClassRoom> n = new HashMap<>();
            n.put(l,c);

          }
        }
         return returnSet;
      }
```

Comment: In this code your key will be the lecture and your value will be the class room. Those can obviously be switched

Comment: But returnSet of this code should be something like [{lecture1:classroom1}, {}, {lecture2:classroom2}.....], what I want is a set like: [{lecture1:classroom1, lecture2:classroom2, lecture3:classroom3}, {lecture1:classroom1, lecture2:classroom3, lecture3:classroom2},{lecture1:classroom2, lecture2:classroom3, lecture3:classroom1}] in my example, I thought they're quite different.

Comment: Although this is a rather inefficient way of using data structures, as u will create a Map for each pair of objects.

Comment: In my perspective, one match is a map whose keyset is the set of all lectures, not a single lecture.

Comment: Then you either have to sort the data structures in advance or designate a part of your algorithm to do a numerical sort on the objects. If you want to do the numerical sort within the algorithm you must give the objects numerical ID's to sort them by.

Comment: I will give u an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with sorted data collections:

```
public Set<Map<Lecture, ClassRoom>> allocateRooms(List<Lecture> lectures, List<ClassRoom> classRooms){

    List<ClassRoom> sortedClassRooms = classRooms
        .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Lecture> sortedLectures = lectures
        .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Set<Map<Lecture, ClassRoom>> returnSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for(Lecture l: sortedLectures){
      for (ClassRoom c: sortedClassRooms){
        Map<Lecture, ClassRoom> n = new HashMap<>();
        n.put(l,c);

      }
    }
     return returnSet;
  }
```

Comment: This is a case where you are using integers id's for your objects

Comment: You don't need to use java8 streams to sort your lists. You can use Collections.sort(); That approach gives less overhead than using Streams as you don't recreate the lists.